# Python requests to send POST request with form-data input

Tags: python, python-requests, attachment, form-data, rest

I have an API which send request to system, we are sending body request as form-data option.

1. Key: Document, value: sample.doc, type: file
2. Key: Request, value: {"Data": {    "Number": "17329937082",    "Format": "MSW"  }}, type: Text

How can achieve this in Pyhton script using Requests. This worked in Postman and I am trying to call this API with python script.

Comment: Have you [read the docs?](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/) Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I used this  "r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')" for normal reqeust, but not sure what to use for "form-data" body request.

I tried the Multipart-Encoded but it is giving 415 unsupported media type error in response

Comment: What did you do to try multipart encoded? Are you sure that endpoint is expecting form-encoded data? Or is it expecting json?

Comment: it is Json response. Sorry, I don't know what to use, just tried something in multipart. What is the best solution to make form-data request in python ?

Answer (score 5):

For form-encoded data, you'll want the `data` kwarg paired with a dictionary, not a string. To demonstrate how this works, I'll use the `requests.Request` object:

```py
from requests import Request
import json

request_dict = {'Data': {'Number': "17329937082", "Format": "MSW"}}

data = {
    'Document': open('sample.doc', 'rb'),   # open in bytes-mode
    'Request': json.dumps(request_dict)     # formats the dict to json text
}

r = Request('GET', 'https://my-url.com', data=data)
req = r.prepare()

r.headers
{'Content-Length': '80595', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

So in a normal request, that will look like:

```py
import requests
import json

request_dict = {'Data': {'Number': "17329937082", "Format": "MSW"}}

data = {
    'Document': open('sample.doc', 'rb'),   # open in bytes-mode
    'Request': json.dumps(request_dict)     # formats the dict to json text
}

r = requests.get('my_url.com', data=data)
```